# include file with json

Tags: php, json

I have this piece of code:

```
    <?php

set_time_limit(0);

// arquivo cujo conteúdo será enviado ao cliente
$dataFileName = 'data.php';


while ( true )
{
    $requestedTimestamp = isset ( $_GET [ 'timestamp' ] ) ? (int)$_GET [ 'timestamp' ] : null;

    // o PHP faz cache de operações "stat" do filesystem. Por isso, devemos limpar esse cache
    clearstatcache();
    $modifiedAt = filemtime( $dataFileName );

    if ( $requestedTimestamp == null || $modifiedAt > $requestedTimestamp )
    {
        $data = file_get_contents( $dataFileName );

        $arrData = array(
            'content' => $data,
            'timestamp' => $modifiedAt
        );      

        $json = json_encode( $arrData );

        echo $json;

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sleep( 1 );
        continue;
    }
}
```

As you can see, i'm saying that `$dataFileName = 'data.php'` further down i make a conten which is equal to the data inside the data.php. I can't for some reason display the data inside php tags in data.php, but i can however display pure text:

```
 <?php 
$hej = "This will not display";
return json_encode($hej);
?>
This will display
```

Hope you can help, and understand my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are echoing out special characters, maybe you need to convert them in order to display it properly.

You can try `htmlentities` which converts those characters -

```
echo htmlentities($data);
```

EDIT-1
For example (assuming data.php contains the php code) -

```
$data = file_get_contents("a.php");
echo htmlentities($data);
/*
    OUTPUT - 
    <?php $hej = "This will not display"; return json_encode($hej); ?> This will display
*/
```

EDIT-2-
If you want to actually want to execute the file and store it's outcome in a string, then output bufferring is what you need.

Basically you execute the php file and the output of the file is stored in a buffer. At the end of it, the buffer contents is copied to a string.

This should work -

```
ob_start();
include("data.php");
$res = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: What is the output? I tried opening the file and echoing out, and it seemed to work properly.

Comment: im only getting the output that's not inside php tag

Comment: @EmilMøllerRinggaard I've added an example as to what I get, check the  edit.

Comment: I have may been unclear in my question, but i want to get the output as php, not the code. I want the code to function if you understand?

Comment: If you want the code to run, try using include instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: @EmilMøllerRinggaard I think now I got your requirement. Check the Edit2.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return json_encode($hej);
```

try

```
echo json_encode($hej);
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you are calling file_get_contents.  That will not parse the PHP in the file.  You'll just get a dump of the file contents, php code included.  I don't think that's really what you want there, but I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do with it, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer! `$dataFileName = 'http://www.dota2u.com/newd2u/longpoll/data.php'`

Thank you for your time!